# Mix Dependency Warning

Tags: elixir

I am taking a Udemy Elixir class from 5 years ago by Stephen Grider. I started on Windows, but have transferred to Linux Mint. Apparently, Elixir was already installed (or updated) to latest version 1.9.1. So, when attempting to:

```
# mix test
==> earmark_parser
warning: the dependency :earmark_parser requires Elixir "~> 1.11" but you are running on v1.9.1
```

I already fixed one of these dependency version issues in the mix.exs file. Where should I be looking for the mismatched dependency above and do you have suggestions to correct it?

Thank you in advance! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Latest Elixir is 1.14, not 1.9.  Be extremely cautious of using any Elixir or Erlang versions that might ship with Linux distros -- problems with them is a recurring topic on StackOverflow because the included versions tend to be out of date.  The error you included says pretty much exactly this: you need at least Elixir 1.11 to run the version of the dependency (`earmark_parser`).  It could be that if you dialed your version of `earmark_parser` back to something older, it would run in Elixir 1.9 fine.  `mix hex.info <package>` and `mix deps.tree` can help you trace out the dependencies of dependencies if you really get stuck.

I would strongly recommend using [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com/) to manage your Elixir versions (and anything else you need to version). In the case of taking an online course, I would recommend using the EXACT version of the Elixir that the course specified -- that will help keep your local work compatible with the course.  Use the same versions of the dependencies too, if possible (you can set these inside the `mix.exs`).

Stephen Grider's course is great, by the way: he's not necessarily an Elixir fan-boy, but he's an effective instructor.